# From main jsp/html, How to access and modify specific iframe elements present inside another iframe controlled by different jsp/html?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have tried some usual document object commands like getElement by id/by tag/by name. They all give null, only bale to identify iframe id"my_dash" but can not access innerHTML. Either gives undefined or nothing in alert. I was trying to access the iframe "iframe_Content_portlet1" to change its src by making a javascript function to work on click link but was not working. Please suggest how to access it....

**Given below is the code one finds in firebug.**
**regarding context from my main code **

```
<tr>
<td colspan="10">

<!--this is the iframe accessible by main jsp-->**
<iframe id="my_dash" width="990px" height="935px" padding-left:="200px" src="http://172.31.144.171:8080/pentaho/content/dashboards?solution=airport&path=%2FMain&action_name=ATM-Dashboard.xdash">

<!--content inside the main iframe-->** 
<html class=" ext-strict" xmlns:pho="http:/www.pentaho.com">
<head>
<body id="ext-gen6" class="pentaho-transparent ext-gecko ext-linux pentaho-page-background">
<div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
<div id="dashboard-content">
<div id="titlebar" class="title" style="position: absolute; display: block; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 990px; height: 23px;">
<h1 id="dashboard-title" class="pageTitle">New Dashboard</h1>
</div>
<div id="widget-area" class="widget-area" scrollexception="true" style="display: block; top: 29px; width: 990px; height: 906px; left: 0px; z-index: 30;">
<div id="widget-area-scroll-shim" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
<div id="select-frame-left"></div>
<div id="select-frame-top"></div>
<div id="select-frame-bottom"></div>
<div id="select-frame-right"></div>

<div id="FilterPanel" class="povContainer" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0px; z-index: 30; display: none;" pho:panel="FilterPanel">
<div id="hbox1" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; width: 990px; height: 300px; left: 0px;">
<div id="Panel_1" class="widgetContainer" style="position: absolute; top: 5px; width: 567.044px; height: 290px; left: 5px; z-index: 30;" pho:panel="Panel_1">
<div class="widget">
<div id="wgtHead-Panel_1" class="wgtHead" ondblclick="pentahoDashboardController.panelTitleDoubleClick('Panel_1')" onclick="pentahoDashboardController.panelTitleClick('Panel_1', true);">
<div id="dataContainer-Panel_1" class="dataContainer" style="height: 265px;">
<div class="rightCorner">
<div class="wgtData">
<div id="content-area-Panel_1" class="panel-contentarea" onclick="pentahoDashboardController.panelTitleClick('Panel_1', false)" style="top: 23px; width: 567.044px; height: 265px; left: 0px;">

<!--this is the iframe I want to access in the same jsp(it is being accessed by another jsp, not included in the main jsp)-->**     

<iframe frameborder="0" src="http://172.31.144.171:8080/pentaho/pentaho-solutions/airport/ATM/scorecard/common1.jsp?dashboard_id=1&portlet_id=1" border="0" style="width:100%;height:100%;border:0px">
<html>
<head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
<div>
<!--this is the iframe I want to access in the same jsp(it is being accessed by another jsp, not included in the main jsp)-->           
<iframe id="iframe_Content_Portlet1" width="100%" height="100%"   style="overflow:hidden;"src="http://172.31.144.171:8080/pentaho/content/reporting/reportviewer/report.html?solution=airport&path=%2FATM%2Fscorecard&name=atm_scorecard.prpt&locale=en_US&username=joe&password=p@@ssw0rd">
<html class="dj_gecko dj_contentbox" xmlns:pho="http:/www.pentaho.com">
<head>
<body class="tundra body pentaho-page-background">
</html>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="wgtFooter-Panel_1" class="wgtFooter">
<div class="rightCorner"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to reach what's inside your frame?

Because something along the lines of `frames["my_dash"].document.getElementById("XXXX")` should work.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.frames for a little doc on frames.